# Why does ido-find-file still show . when ido-ignore-directories seems to exclude it?

Tags: ido, ido-find-file

I have my `ido-ignore-directories` set to the standard value:

```
("\\`CVS/" "\\`\\.\\./" "\\`\\./")
```

The third regexp, `` "\`\./" `` should ignore the current directory, as near as I can tell. However, it doesn't:

```
Find file read only: ~/{. | Desktop/ | Documents/ | ...}
```

If it matters, I have <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-f</kbd> bound to `ido-find-file-read-only`. This is with emacs 24.3.1. How do I fix it?

Comment: Dunno (I don't use Ido), but you will notice that Ido shows `.`, not `./`, whereas it shows `Desktop/`. Whether that is just inconsistent output on the part of Ido, or whether you need to explicitly match `.` in addition to `./`, I don't know. You are currently matching explicitly against the `/`, and the candidate shown by Ido is `.` - no slash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drew's comment inspired me to look closer at ido's settings. Turns out there's an `ido-show-dot-for-dired` setting that will *always* put `.` as the first element in the completion list so you can quickly do a dired on the directory. I, unbeknownst to me, had that set to `t` instead of `nil`. This is what I get for starting with someone else's `.emacs` file.